# Typescript: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-filtering

I am getting this error on line:

```
return filter ? value.filter(element => element.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1) : value;
```

when `element.type` is an empty string (filtering empty column). How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the message states: `element.type` is `undefined`. Add a check on that in your `filter` call. Something like this, what you put depends on what you are expecting back and I can only guess at that.

```
return filter 
    ? value.filter(element => element.type && element.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1) 
    : value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error itself gives the solution as the value passed to change into lowercase is null or undefined.
To solve such errors, put the statements for the data to be passed in an `if` statement.

Like :

```
if(somevalue != null || somevalue != undefined)
{ ... }
```

Putting the statements inside `if` statement solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well said, error itself gives the solution as the value passed to change into lowercase is `null` or `undefined`.

Just add to your line of code, where you see error coming

```
if(somevalue != null || somevalue != undefined)
{ ... }
```