# add condition to Javascript filter

Tags: javascript

I want to filter users by name and or lastname. but I´m getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined


const users = [{name: 'john', lastname: "doe"}, {name: 'mary'}]

let searchName = "jo"
let searchLastName = ""

users.filter((user) =>
    user.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchName.toLowerCase())

    && user.lastname
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchLastName.toLowerCase())
)
```

how can I check for lastname only if user has lastname. (i know they always have name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542137/typescript-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variant A: `lastName` check only if `lastName` is set:

```js
users.filter((user) =>
    user.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchName.toLowerCase())

    && (
        !user.lastname
        || user.lastname
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchLastName.toLowerCase())
    )
)
```

Variant B: additional condition that `lastName` must be set:

```js
users.filter((user) =>
    user.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchName.toLowerCase())

    && user.lastname
    && user.lastname
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchLastName.toLowerCase())
    )
)
```

Comment: Whether you want A or B depends on your use case. Both should avoid the `TypeError`.

Comment: `&&` and `||` expressions evaluate their operands as boolean values, so `user.lastName` gets converted to a boolean value (`true` / `false`) first. As Pac0 wrote, empty strings, `null` or `undefined` are converted to `false`, but other values are also [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: I will go with option A it works fine with `!searchLastName || ....` thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a check on the existence of the variable with JS automatic boolean coercion :

```
&& user.lastname   // This will return false if empty, null or undefined
&& user.lastname
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(searchLastName.toLowerCase())
```